# Only Google Maps Android API V1 is activated, how to activate v2 on Developer Console?

Tags: android, api, maps

I'm trying to use Google Maps API on my application. All configurations on the app and Console Developer was made. Including creating project, keys...

But this error bellow still persisting on Android Studio Log Cat:

> [Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.]
>   [Ensure that the following Android Key exists]

Searching on the console's developer, I have identified that the actually enabled API is 1. However, I can not find the option to install the 2.

Comment: Same here. There's no v2 available in my console, only "Google Maps Android API".